# How can i use stripe.redirectToCheckout in my asp.net webforms?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to redirect my users to stripe secure checkout option instead of getting their credit card details in my website using stripe gateway. How can i accomplish it using stripe.redirectToCheckout. Didn't found and proper example or documentation.

Comment: I would recommend checkout out this video which was made by one of Stripe's developer advocates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odOyfK94yGo. That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thank you , i think i got the concept from this video but not completely working though